# How to adjust Context Menu?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have description of default context menu in data template. I want to add some items to it in the code. I thought that all I need to do is handle ContextMenuOpening event. But ContextMenu is null while handling. I initialize it and add the items but when the menu is opened there are no default items. What should I do have default items and new one in the menu?

Comment: share some code, what and how you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. However, you seem to have this website confused with MSDN, where you can find out how to use the various controls in WPF. This website has a particular purpose, which you can find out about from the Stack Overflow [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Your question does *not* fit what is required here and as such, I have voted to close it for being 'off topic'. One clue for you is that you should be declaring your `ContextMenu` in XAML. Another clue is that you can search for this kind of help in Google. Try searching for *WPF `ContextMenu` tutorial*

Comment: [ContextMenu Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx) from MSDN, [Many search results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=WPF+ContextMenu+Tutorial) from Google.

Comment: There is DataTemplate in xaml that have the following:
`<Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding OpenTableConfigurationCommand, Converter={StaticResource nullToVisibilityConverter}}">
          <MenuItem Header="Table Configurationn" CommandParameter="Details" Command="{Binding OpenTableConfigurationCommand}" >
            <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Controls;component/Images/TableConfiguration.png" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
          </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
      </Grid.ContextMenu>`

Comment: The handler here:
`void GridControl_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Context menu is being opend.");

            var element = e.Source as FrameworkElement;

            if (element.ContextMenu == null)
            {
                this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();    
            }
            
            var mi = new MenuItem();
            mi.Header = "Do Something Else";
            element.ContextMenu.Items.Add(mi);
        }`

Comment: I did some searches but it didn't help. I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613568.aspx) but it doesn't work how I need.

Comment: The solution. I have collection of menu items (ContextMenuItem) in data source. Also I use CompositeCollection in xaml description of the menu:
`<ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <MenuItem Header="Table Configurationn" />                            
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ContextMenuItemsBridge}}"/>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                </ContextMenu>`

Comment: There is one thing in this solution. I need to have a special static resource as source for the collection which is defined like that:
` <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ContextMenuItemsBridge" Source="{Binding Path=ContextMenuItems}" />`. 
It is because CompositeCollection doesn't have visual properties and as a result it can't inherit data context.